# Move left, right or continue walking while following an CLLocation destination in iOS + objective c

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation, compass-geolocation, magnetometer

I have to point the arrow to the defined destination location (in my sample code it's CLLocation with latitude 70.0 and longitude -50.0) and guide the user saying "Great! continue walking" if the user is moving with 5 degrees left or right of the pointer and "You are going the wrong direction. Move right" if the user goes more than 5 degrees in the left of the pointer and "You are going in the wrong direction. Move left" if the user is moving right of the arrow. Pointing arrow to the defined location is working perfectly for me but user walking hint is not working as expected. Its saying move left or move right most of the cases but sometimes it's saying move right instead of move left and I have to move whole one complete turn to reach the location pointer. I haven't included the code to calculate bearing angle as the code will be very long.

Part of the code which is used for guiding the the walk is:

> ```
>    CGFloat toMove = 360 + [self radiansToDegrees:yourLocationBearing];
>     if ( toMove > 360) {
>         toMove = toMove - 360;
>     }        
>
>     if(newHeading.trueHeading < toMove - 5){
>         self.headingInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are going in the wrong direction. Move right" ];
>     }
>     else if (newHeading.trueHeading > toMove + 5 ){
>         self.headingInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are going in the wrong direction. Move left" ];
>     } else{
>         self.headingInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Great! Continue walking"];
>     }
> ```

My question is how to achieve the walking hint properly? I am getting the problem in my case when I just pass the True North, its saying move right and I have to make a whole round to get the message "Great! Continue walking".

The complete code for pointing the arrow and guiding the walk is:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CompassRedo-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *headingInfo;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.yourLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:70.0 longitude:-50.0];        

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

    if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]){
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{
    if(locations.lastObject!=nil && locations.lastObject.horizontalAccuracy > 0){
        self.latestLocation = locations.lastObject;
    }
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{        

    CGFloat yourLocationBearing = [self.latestLocation bearingToLocationRadian:self.yourLocation];

    CGFloat originalHeading = yourLocationBearing - [self degreesToRadians: newHeading.trueHeading];
    CGFloat heading = originalHeading;

    switch (UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown:
            heading = -originalHeading;
            break;
        default:
            heading = originalHeading;
            break;
    }

    CGFloat adjAngle = [self getAdjustableAngle];

    heading = (CGFloat)[self degreesToRadians: adjAngle] + heading ;

    CGFloat toMove = 360 + [self radiansToDegrees:yourLocationBearing];
    if ( toMove > 360) {
        toMove = toMove - 360;
    }        

    if(newHeading.trueHeading < toMove - 5){
        self.headingInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are going in the wrong direction. Move right" ];
    }
    else if (newHeading.trueHeading > toMove + 5 ){
        self.headingInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are going in the wrong direction. Move left" ];
    } else{
        self.headingInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Great! Continue walking"];
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{
                         self->imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(heading);
                     }];

}

-(CGFloat) getAdjustableAngle{
    //Adjustment according to device oorientation
    BOOL isFaceDown = NO;
    switch (UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown:
            isFaceDown = YES;
            break;
        default:
            isFaceDown = NO;
            break;
    }

    CGFloat adjAngle;
    switch (UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            adjAngle = 90;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            adjAngle = -90;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown:
            adjAngle = 0;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            adjAngle = isFaceDown ? 180 : - 180;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return adjAngle;
}

-(CGFloat) degreesToRadians : (CGFloat) degrees{
    return  degrees * M_PI / 180;
}
-(CGFloat) radiansToDegrees : (CGFloat) radians{
    return  radians * 180 / M_PI;
}
@end
```